# How to dynamically add achors, links and endpoints to an element using jsplumb?

Tags: drag-and-drop, jsplumb

I have used jsplumb for dragging an element from one div and drop it to another div. It is working fine. Here's my code:

```
var counter = 0;
var x = null;
//Make element draggable
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit',
    revert: true
});
$(".droppable").droppable({
            accept: '.drag',
            activeClass: "drop-area",
            drop: function(e, ui) {
                    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id !== "") {
                        x = ui.helper.clone();
                        <!--  ui.helper.remove(); -->
                        x.draggable({
                            helper: 'original',
                            cursor: 'move',
                            containment: '.droppable',
                            tolerance: 'fit',
                            drop: function(event, ui) {
                                $(ui.draggable).remove();
                            }
                        });
```

I have created another example where I am creating four blocks and making them connect by linking them dynamically using jsplumb. Similar kind of working example is in the link https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/flowchart/index.html

Now I want to integrate both these. I want to drag and drop and dynamically create links, anchors, and endpoints between them. How to do that?